# How do I solve name service error in sbcl with slime?

Tags: emacs, sbcl, slime

I've recently installed SLIME mode and I can't get it to work. Upon startup (`M-x slime`) it throws out this error:

```
This is SBCL 2.1.1, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* ; loading #P"/home/logan/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.26.1/swank-loader.lisp"
WARNING:
   redefining EMACS-INSPECT (#<SB-PCL:SYSTEM-CLASS COMMON-LISP:T>) in DEFMETHOD

debugger invoked on a SB-BSD-SOCKETS:HOST-NOT-FOUND-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1004DD81F3}>:
  Name service error in "getaddrinfo": -2 (Name or service not known)

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [USE-VALUE] Try a port other than 0
  1: [ABORT    ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-BSD-SOCKETS:NAME-SERVICE-ERROR "getaddrinfo" -2)
   source: (= ERRNO SB-BSD-SOCKETS-INTERNAL::NETDB-INTERNAL)
```

If I abort I can still use the repl fine. However, I'm trying to create a common lisp source block in org mode like so:

```
#+begin_src lisp
(princ "test")
#+end_src
```

Upon running this block `C-c C-c` all I get is:

```
Polling "/tmp/slime.xxxx" .. 123 (Abort with 'M-x slime-abort-connection')
```

What does it mean by "name service error in getaddrinfo"? I've tried searching for this but I can't find anything.

I'm on artix linux btw if that helps.

Comment: It could be that the default `*loopback-interface*`, "localhost", is not resolved to "127.0.0.1" on your system (I don't know Artix); in `~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.26.1/start-swank.lisp` I would add `:interface "127.0.0.1"` in the call to `create-server` to test if it keeps happening

Comment: @coredump Nope that didn't change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is kind of a face-palm moment. I currently live on a college campus so I had my /etc/hosts point all hosts to my assigned IPv4. Had to add a localhost host in that file.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration